# How to solve dangling else in Coco/R?

Tags: parsing, cocor, dangling-else

I have a dangling-else problem in Coco/R. I try to understand the [Coco/R User Manual](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/Doc/UserManual.pdf) and I ask Google, but I can't solve the problem on my own.

I simplified my problem to the following Coco/R grammar (saved in `new4.atg`):

```
COMPILER Expr 
CHARACTERS

    digit   = '0'..'9'. 
    letter  = 'A'..'Z'.

TOKENS

    number  = digit { digit }.
    name    = letter { digit | letter }.    

PRODUCTIONS

    Expr = Test | Id Test.  
    Test = Test2.   
    Test2=Id | "(" Test ")".        
    Id=IdName|IdNumber.         
    IdName = name.  
    IdNumber = number.      

END Expr.
```

When I want to build the compiler with `coco.bat`, I get this answer:

```
Coco/R (Dec 22, 2014)
checking
new 4.atg(15,1): LL1 warning in Expr: number is start of several alternatives
new 4.atg(15,1): LL1 warning in Expr: name is start of several alternatives
parser + scanner generated
0 errors detected
```

In the [best result in Google](https://sites.google.com/site/structuredparsing/java-syntax-1-5-parser/2-4-2-coco-r---fixing-grammar-warnings), I have read that I can declare `IF(isXXXFollowYYY())` statement, but I don't how and if it's the best solution.
(In my example: `Expr = Test | If(isTestFollowID)Id Test`. But where is `isTestFollowID` declared?)

I want to get no warnings, when I start `coco.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is ambiguous.

From `Expr`, upon seeing an `Id` token, the parser can go either

```
Expr -> Test -> Test2 -> Id
```

or

```
Expr -> Id
```

An LL(1) parser will not know which path to take.

The immediate problem can be fixed by pulling `Id` out into a lead-in optional component in your `Expr` production:

Instead of

```
Expr = Test | Id Test.
```

you can do

```
Expr = [Id] Test .
```

However the `Test` production can also match an `Id` at its beginning, so it appears that further refactorings will be needed to make the grammar LL(1).

Comment: I have test your solution. `Expr = [Id] Test.`. The result is the same. (_LL1 warning in Expr: number is start & successor of deletable structure_) What further refactorings will be needed?